# How to make last child not to fade?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, css-selectors

We have horizontal scrolling divs here. Want to remove the fading from right side for the last div scrollable. I gave fading effect to parent div (d-flex fading here). Tried using nth child for child div, but its not working.
Is there any way to do that ? Thank you

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="d-flex fading">
      <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
         <div class="card h-100 py-2">
            <div class="card-body">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
     <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
         <div class="card h-100 py-2">
            <div class="card-body">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
<div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
         <div class="card h-100 py-2">
            <div class="card-body">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
<div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
         <div class="card h-100 py-2">
            <div class="card-body">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
     <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
         <div class="card h-100 py-2">
            <div class="card-body">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

```
    .fading{
      -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 0%, white 40%);
      mask-image: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 0%, white 40%);
    }
    .card{
      display:block;
      background-color:green;
      border:2px solid black;
      overflow-x:auto;
      whitespace:nowrap;
    }  
    .card-body{
      display:block;
      background-color:green;
    }
   .card:nth-child(n){
      -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 0%, white 0%);
      mask-image: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 0%, white 0%);
   }
```

[please see the example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HatVA.png)

Comment: Have you tried adding `position: relative` and `z-index: 10` to the last child?

Comment: Yes, tried that. Not working

Comment: So you want fading on the background but obviously not on the content of the final div? If so I think you need to apply the gradient to the background of the parent div and not the entire parent div itself. There is some info about it here at CSS Tricks https://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/

Comment: there is no `overflow: auto` on `d-flex fading` div could that be the problem?